# Hosted SaaS provider for Flash based one-on-one video chat

Tags: web-development, video-conferencing, flash, saas

I'm looking for a ready-to-go, preferably pay-for-what-you-use hosted solution for a website-embeddable video chat solution **based on Flash** or at least offering a **Flash fallback.** This is for a video chat system which already uses WebRTC and [Tokbox](http://tokbox.com), whom I'm very happy with, but which only works on Chrome/Firefox/Opera and requires a proprietary plugin to be installed for other browsers. To make this more widely compatible I'm looking for a feasible fallback solution using the widely installed Flash plugin.

The solution should be ready to go and have rough feature parity with Tokbox, which specifically means for my purposes:

- on demand server-side recording of the conversation
- embeddable into customised application (meaning not a full-stack solution, just an API)
- reasonable customisation of appearance (including things like muting one or both parties)

I could be setting up a Wowza or Red5 server myself and somehow code the necessary client-side Flash implementation, but I'd really prefer all this to be available as SaaS and not have to worry about it much.